# Infinite page scroll function with Mysql not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am getting data from mysql but page scroll is not working.

It is just displaying 10 results(1-10), and if i scroll down not getting any results.

**This is my load.php file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="load_style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(window).scroll(function ()
    {
      if($(body).height() <= $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height())
      {
        loadmore();
      }
    });

    function loadmore()
    {
      var val = document.getElementById("row_no").value;
      $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'get_resultts.php',
      data: {
       getresult:val
      },
      success: function (response) {
      var content = document.getElementById("all_rows");
      content.innerHTML = content.innerHTML+response;

      // We increase the value by 10 because we limit the results by 10
      document.getElementById("row_no").value = Number(val)+10;
      }
      });
    }
    </script>

    </head>

    <body>

      <h1>Load Results From Database On Page Scroll Using jQuery,Ajax And PHP</h1>
      <div id="all_rows">
        <?php

          $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "text");
          $sql="select text from text limit 0,10";
          $select = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
          while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($select))
          {
            echo "<p class='rows'>".$row['text']."</p>";
          }
        ?>
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" id="row_no" value="10">

    </body>
    </html>
```

**This is get_resultts.php**

```
<?php

  if(isset($_POST['getresult']))
  {
    $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "text");

    $no = $_POST['getresult'];
    $sql = "select text from text limit $no,10";
    $select = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select))
    {
      echo "<p class='rows'>".$row['text']."</p>";
    }
    exit();
  }

?>
```

Any Hint/help is appreciated.

Comment: provide more debug data, have you some error in debug console?

Comment: i am not getting any kind of errors. But page scroll function not working. For example 1 2 3 4 ..,. 10 results are displaying from mysql but page is not loading any further.. sorry i am beginner to this

Comment: what is in your content variable?

Comment: just text such as hiii hello

Comment: please help me..

Comment: If you look at the post-request in console, what does the script return? Does it even get a return?

Comment: I am getting results from 1-10.. sorry iam beginner to this.. hope i replied what you have asked me.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems here.  The first is that you're not referring to the body tag correctly -- you should use :

```
$("body")...
```

and not $(body) as you've done in your script.

The second problem is that it's possible that the content won't fill the space available -- if the content isn't high enough to scroll, then your scroll event will never fire, so even once the body tag is corrected, the event may never try to fire.  You could easily put in place some kind of loop in the document ready event:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
   ... (repeat similar check until content fills space) ...
}
```

The last problem is that, in response to the scroll, you could easily get multiple triggers of the loadmore() function.  This would lead to your page triggering multiple parallel ajax requests with an identical row-number, and you'd get a large number of repeated requests appearing in sequence.

To prevent that, you should try to only have one such ajax query running at any time.  There are multiple ways of doing this, but one approach is to track the number of active Ajax queries you have open, and only proceed if the previous queries have completed.  For example:

```
var countAjax = 0;
function loadMore() {
    if (countAjax>0) return;
    $.ajax({
        beforeSend: function() {
            countAjax++;
        }, 
        ... (other settings) ...
        success: function(response) {
            countAjax--;
            ... (other success events) ...
        },
        error: function() {
            countAjax--;
            ... (other error events) ...
        }
    });
}
```

By doing this, you ensure that the page is only ever executing one ajax request at a time, rather than multiple ones in parallel -- the query must either complete successfully or trigger an error for the counter to be decremented back to zero again, and won't try another query until that has happened.

Comment: Here is the demo which i want to get like this page scroll [link] (http://talkerscode.com/webtricks/demo/demo_load-results-from-database-on-page-scroll-using-jquery-ajax-and-php.php}

Comment: If you look at the example on the link you provided, you can see the data-repeating error that I mention -- the page produces multiple copies of the same ajax request and pulls back several sets of duplicate data.